# DateTimepicker not working for 1 specific date

Tags: vb.net, datetime, dataset, reportviewer2008

I have a windows program that uses a couple datasets to pull information and put it into a table.  I used 2 Datetimepickers `Datetimepicker1` and `Datetimepicker2`.  In my Command button `Command Button 1` I have the code to run the and fill the datatables using the Datetimepickers to fill the parameters.  This works great, however on "2/16/2013" it does not work.  It looks like if the first dataset is empty it cancels the rest of the report.  I need to add a check to see if the dataset is 0, if it is Then move on to filling the next dataset... My code is below for the Command button... Any Ideas?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If DateTimePicker1.Value > DateTimePicker2.Value Then
            MsgBox("Start Date cannot be greater than End Date!")
        Else


            Me.Package1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet.Package1, DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTimePicker2.Value.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1))

            Me.Package2TableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet.Package2, DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTimePicker2.Value.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1))

            Me.Package3TableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet.Package3, DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTimePicker2.Value.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1))

            Me.Package4TableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet.Package4, DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTimePicker2.Value.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1))



            Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: You say any other date. Does that include "3/16/2013"? Also, what error message are you seeing when you say it "Doesn't work"?

Comment: I just do not receive any records.  And I know there are 25.  I guess the question is, what if the first dataset is empty?  would that cause it?  Does it not know to go to the next dataset and continue filling?

Comment: I guess since you are not assigning the value to `Datetimepicker2` the change is not reflected, so you need to assign the changes back to `Datetimepicker2.Value`. Is this your problem ?

Comment: I found the problem, I just don't know how to fix it... IF the first dataset is empty... the rest of the report doesn't generate (I have each dataset dump to the same report in order... How do I Fix that?

Comment: Why don't you check that your dataset returns records before populating and then you can skip sections that are blank?

Comment: where would I check for blank records?  At the command button level?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (pseudo code as not a computer with VS):

```
if (theDataSetYouWantToCheck.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    // Output to report...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fill the report viewer for some reason.  It kills the dataset fill and leaves the report viewer blank.  Remember I would have to do 4 if statements as I have 4 different datasets.  Perhaps it's best to just put all the queries into 1.

Comment: Yes, you could return 4 tables and access as per the code snippet. i.e.  Tables[0] ... Tables[3] etc.

Comment: I just made it all into 1 query, 1 table, and returned the results that way.